# enviar parametros en vue desde un to

Tags: vue.js

Soy nuevo en este tema... Tengo un componente donde tengo un contenido estático y una lista desplegable donde el usuario elige entre 3 opciones y de acuerdo a ello trae la respectiva vista, ahora me piden que desde el navbar (que es otro componente) haga la misma lista desplegable y desde allí también se pueda acceder a esas mismas 3 opciones, es decir se tendrá q acceder al componente y de allí a la función donde me permite cargar las 3 vistas. Me dijeron que eso es con parametros, pero no tengo idea de ello y he visto la documentacion y tutoriales, pero no doy.

Mi pregunta es como hago para que desde el navbar (lista desplegable) pueda ir a ese componente y que de acuerdo a lo que eliga vaya y permita ver esa vista.

Espero me haya hecho entender.

COMPONENTE inicio_portal.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <section id="poldeseguridad" class="container d-flex justify-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 p-3">
                    <br>
                    <hr>
                    <h4 class="subtitulo" >Objetivos del SGSST</h4>
                    <br>
                    <div v-for="objetivo in objetivos" :key="objetivo.id">
                        <p><i class="bi bi-check-circle p-2"></i> {{ objetivo.nombre }}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="etapas">
                        <b-dropdown dropright text="Etapas" right>
                            <b-dropdown-item class="dropdown-item pr-0" @click="cargarEtapas(1)"><a  target="_self" style="color: black  !important;" class="nav-link p-0">Etapa 1 a la 4</a></b-dropdown-item>
                            <b-dropdown-item class="dropdown-item pr-0" @click="cargarEtapas(2)"><a  target="_self" style="color: black  !important;" class="nav-link p-0">Etapa 5 a la 9</a></b-dropdown-item>
                            <b-dropdown-item class="dropdown-item pr-0" @click="cargarEtapas(3)"><a  target="_self" style="color: black  !important;" class="nav-link p-0">Etapa 10 a la 14</a></b-dropdown-item>
                       
                        </b-dropdown>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <etapa1a4 v-if="etapa_1"></etapa1a4>
        <etapa5a9 v-if="etapa_5"></etapa5a9>
        <etapa10a14 v-if="etapa_10"></etapa10a14>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import etapa1a4 from '../../components/Portal/Etapa1a4.vue';
import etapa5a9 from '../../components/Portal/Etapa5a9.vue';
import etapa10a14 from '../../components/Portal/Etapa10a14.vue';

export default{
    name: 'inicio_portal',
    components: {
        etapa1a4,
        etapa5a9,
        etapa10a14,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            objetivos: [],
            etapa_1: false,
            etapa_5: false,
            etapa_10: false,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.consultaBase();
    },
    methods: {
        consultaBase() {
            axios.get('/portalObjetivos').then((res) => {
                if(res.status == 200) {
                    // console.log(res.data)
                    this.objetivos = res.data
                }
            })
            .catch((res) => {
                console.log('error de consulta')
                console.log(res);
            });
        },
        cargarEtapas(etapa) {
           if(etapa == 1) {
            this.etapa_1 = true
            this.etapa_5 = false
            this.etapa_10 = false
           }
           else if(etapa == 2) {
            this.etapa_1 = false
            this.etapa_5 = true
            this.etapa_10 = false
           }
           else if(etapa == 3) {
            this.etapa_1 = false
            this.etapa_5 = false
            this.etapa_10 = true
           }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

navbar.vue

```
<b-navbar-nav>
        <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Portal SGSST" right variant="none">
          <b-dropdown-item class="dropdown-item pr-0" to="inicio_portal"><a  target="_self" style="color: black  !important;" class="nav-link p-0">Etapa 1 a la 4</a></b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item class="dropdown-item pr-0" to="inicio_portal"><a  target="_self" style="color: black  !important;" class="nav-link p-0">Etapa 5 a la 9</a></b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item class="dropdown-item pr-0" to="inicio_portal"><a  target="_self" style="color: black  !important;" class="nav-link p-0">Etapa 10 a la 14</a></b-dropdown-item>
        </b-nav-item-dropdown>
</b-navbar-nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas usar el Router de Vue, con parámetros se refiere a enviar los datos que necesitas cuando vayas a otra dirección. Esos `if-else` anidados quien sabe que hacen ahí. Tienes que definir una carpeta `router` con un archivo `index.js` y ahí dentro pones las rutas que vas a tener.

Ejemplo:
Como ves acá envías el id en los props, si tus 3 componentes son iguales con diferentes datos entonces solamente necesitas 1, y los datos que vas a cargar los mandas en el `router.params.id` o lo que sea que necesites, `ID` es solo un ejemplo.

```
export default {
    {
      path: "etapa",
      name: "etapa",
      component: () =>
        import(
          /* webpackChunkName: "NOMBRE_COMPONENTE" */ "@PATH_DEL_COMPONENTE"
        ),
      props: (router) => {
        return {
          id: router.params.id,
        };
      },
    },
}
```

mientras que en tu `navbar` necesitas algo así:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'etapa' }">Etapa</router-link>
```

También puedes hacer `to="/etapa"` pero es más claro y preciso hacerlo con el nombre de la ruta.

Te dejo la documentación del Router:

[Introduction | Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/introduction.html)